# How to segment/cluster a sequence of time series where the distance of the segments/clusters is bigger than 1 day?

Tags: python, time-series

I need to cluster/segment a sequence of time series, where every cluster should have a bigger distance than 1 day. Is it also possible to find patterns, which are connected to other data?

I am using `TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters, metric="dtw")` from tslearn a python-libary now, but i have to define the n_clusters, which is not useful. I need to define the distance between the clusters.